# .net library to draw shapes images text etc, using GDI+

Tags: .net, gdi+

A stupid question here:

is there such a library to do these stuff?
I want a more advanced library than system.drawing namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at Open Diagram at codeplex:

http://opendiagram.codeplex.com/

Comment: it's pretty cool, but I want to draw my own drawings, the lib seems can't do low level stuff.

Comment: If you want a retained mode graphics system, then WPF is probably a better bet .... Open Diagram does provide you with a graphics object to do your own drawing within each class.

Answer (score 2):

It's not GDI+, but have you considered using the [System.Windows.Media.Imaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.aspx) api (New since .Net 3.0).

It offers some better drawing abilities like the [DrawGeometry(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.drawgeometry.aspx) method.

First create a [DrawingVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.aspx) and a [DrawingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.aspx):

```
DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
DrawingContext dc = visual.RenderOpen();
```

Then draw stuff on it:

```
dc.DrawRectangle(...);
dc.DrawText(...);
dc.DrawGeometry(...);
etc...
```

Make sure you close it:

```
 dc.Close();
```

Once you have your visual object you can render it in WPF window or render it to a file. You can also use use a WPF [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx) as the visual object in the first place.

There are some good MS Tutorials on [Drawing Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751619.aspx), [Using DrawingVisual Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254.aspx) and [WPF Graphics Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373.aspx).